# Why I am getting floating point exception

Tags: c++, floating-point

I don't think there is any point in my code I am reaching zero or dividing it with zero so can anyone help me why I am getting floating point exception for input 20 75

I am just calculating factorial for 2*n -1 and diving it with factorial of n and n-1 but I don't know where my code is getting zero or something else is reason

```
int fact(int num) {
    if(num == 1 || num == 0) return 1;
    else return (num*fact(num-1));
}
int Solution::solve(int A) {
    int val1 = fact(A-1);
    int val2 = fact(A-1+A-1);
    int ans = (val2/((val1*val1)%1000000007))%1000000007;
    return (ans/A)%1000000007;
}
```

for A = 20 or A = 75 I am getting floating point exception

Comment: Because in the old days names were extremely limited, integer division by zero triggers a floating point exception. `(val1*val1)%1000000007) can resolve to 0, so `(val2/((val1*val1)%1000000007))` can go BOOOOM!

Comment: thanks, I liked how you think of a solution it was a very clever way and I also hoped that it will work but unfortunately still I am facing floating point exception

Comment: "_I don't think..._" - When I'm at that point,I bring forth the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add much but if you would change all `int var = ...` variables to
`long long int var = ...`
(while I think that the `long long int` is not recommended to use according to Google's Style Guide) it would work also with input of `20` becuase of the reasons mensioned in 
previous comments:

```
long long int fact(long long int num) {
    if(num == 1 || num == 0) return 1;
    else return (num*fact(num-1));
}
int Solution::solve(int A) {
    long long int val1 = fact(A-1);
    long long int val2 = fact(A-1+A-1);
    long long int ans = (val2/((val1*val1)%1000000007))%1000000007;
    return (ans/A)%1000000007;
}
```

Comment: The largest input solvable signed with 64 bit integer is A = 11.

Answer (score 1):

With input A = 20, you invoke `fact(20 - 1)` and `fact(20 - 1 + 20 - 1)` which are `fact(19)` `fact(38)`. Factorial of 19 is 121645100408832000 and factorial of 38 is 523022617466601111760007224100074291200000000.

On typical PC, the largest representable value for `int` is 2147483647 which is less than either of the above factorials that you attempt to calculate. Your program overflows a signed integer, and behaviour of the program is undefined.

> I don't think there is any point in my code I am ... dividing it with zero

`(val1*val1)%1000000007` could be zero for some values of `val1`. Therefore `val2/((val1*val1)%1000000007)` may be dividing by zero. A simple case where that is the case is when `val1` is zero and another case is where it is 1000000007. You may be thinking that `val1` can never be either of those values since they are not factorials, but it can totally be either value when you have signed overflow in your program.

The largest factorial representable by as 32 bit integer is 12! and thus the largest input that your function can solve is A = 7.

Comment: Even a calculation of 13! will overflow a 32 bit signed integer.     So calculation of `fact(A-1)` would give undefined behaviour for `A` of 14 or more.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your help now I have modified my code and made it like following,

int fact(int num) {
    if(num == 1 || num == 0) return 1;
    else return (num*(fact(num-1)%1000000007))%1000000007;
}
int Solution::solve(int A) {
    int val1 = fact(A-1);
    int val2 = fact(A-1+A-1)%1000000007;
    int ans = (val2/((val1*val1)%1000000007));
    cout << val1 << " " << val2 << " " << ans;
    return (ans/A)%1000000007;
}
but after that for A = 10 I am getting 0 and an answer and val1,val2,ans as 362880 -832225753 10
and you tell me why?
it would be great help

Comment: What I have done is added the %1000000007 while getting the factorial so that it stays within the range of int but still I am getting abnormal behaviour

Comment: @ParikshitSingh - The undefined behaviour happens when an overflow occurs in the `fact()` function - in other words in the calculation of `val1` and `val2`.   Subsequently calculating `(val1*val1)%1000000007` doesn't magically fix that.